# What is the best way to show different menus for different user group in Vue-JS?

Tags: vue.js

I am learning Vue-JS, but I can't understand best way to show different menu for different user groups: quests, users, admins.

Should I use any global variable and check it value from Vue? Is the next code is right for such case?

```
  var userMenu = Vue.component("usermenu", Vue.extend({
    template: "#usermenu",
    components: {
     guestView: Vue.extend({
        template: `
              <p>Quest</p>
            `}),

      userView: Vue.extend({
        template: `
                <p>User</p>
            `}),     

      adminView: Vue.extend({
        template: `
                <p>Admin</p>
            `})

    }
```

How I can switch between views?

Also I tried to do something like:

```
  var GuestMenu = Vue.extend({
        template: `
             <p>Guest</p>
            `});

   var UserMenu = Vue.extend({
        template: `
                <p>User</p>`});     

   var AdminMenu = Vue.extend({
        template: `
                <p>Admin</p>
                `});


   Vue.use(VueRouter)

var App = Vue.extend({
    components: {
      'topmenu': AdminMenu // how to change template here to another??
    }
})
```

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/szwxvze2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`v-if`](http://vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#v-if) or [`v-show`](http://vuejs.org/guide/conditional.html#v-if). You just need some way to know if the user is an admin, a guest or any other. So, let's say that you add a property to the userMenu component called `userType`, then to render the proper menu you should have something like this (I will assume that you are using `browserify` with [`vueify`](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify-example) for better understanding, if not, just wrapp the whole code in a single file).

**app.js**

```
var Vue = require('vue'); //unnecesary if you include vue through a <script> tag
var Menu= require('./components/menu.vue'); //if you are not using browseify, 
                                            //add the menu component code in app.js

new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  components: {
    topMenu: Menu    
  }
});
```

**Menu Component**

```
<template>
    <admin-view v-if="userType === 'admin'"></admin-view>
    <user-view v-if="userType === 'user'"></user-view>
    <guest-view v-if="userType === 'guest'"></guest-view>
</template>
<script>
import GuestMenu from 'guestmenu.vue' //if you are using vueify you can use es6 syntax
import AdminMenu from 'adminmenu.vue'
import UserMenu from 'usermenu.vue'

export default {
  data(){
    return {
      userType : '' //This should be handled by some model or any other way
    }
  },
  components : {
    GuestMenu ,
    AdminMenu ,
    UserMenu 
  }
}
</script>
```

**GuestMenu Component**

```
<template>
    <p>Guest</p>
</template>
```

**AdminMenuComponent**

```
<template>
    <p>Admin</p>
</template>
```

**UserMenuComponent**

```
<template>
    <p>User</p>
</template>
```

I hope that now is clear enough. As an advice, I think that if you are interested in using vue, you should use it with browserify or webpack, like in this example, it helps for [modularity](http://vuejs.org/guide/application.html#Modularization)

Comment: Do I need to touch this:
```var App = Vue.extend({
    components: {
      'topmenu': AdminMenu
    }
})
```
I thought that here I need somehow ho change `AdminMenu` to another views?

Comment: Instead of changing dinamically the component I would have that `App` component, as a root component, and then a `Menu` component with the code in my answer, so inside the `Menu` component there are three child components that are rendered properly according to the user profile. Note that the `v-if` directive, actually creates `only` the component to be shown.

Comment: Could you show me any code example to better understand idea? I really googled, but do not found any good example that illustrate my problem.

I can't understand why I need yet another `Menu` component, and what should include `App` component.

`userType` where I should to declare it?

Comment: look at my edit, and make sure to have a look to the vueify example link :)

Comment: could I solve my task with http://vuejs.org/guide/components.html#Dynamic_Components 

I am noob in JS, so it's a little bit hard to understand logic. So I need easiest way